# Replace part of filename by directory name

Tags: linux, shell

I have folders named `ACB*` and in it among many other files, a couple of files called `scanAC_*`

I want to delete the part called `scanAC` and replace it with the directory name it is in.

For example, directory `ACB_200315` containes file `scanAC_typefile_2S.dcm`, I want that lastfile to become `ACB_200315_typefile_2S.dcm`

What I have tried right now (Linux, SSH, rename option not available) but does not work:

```
for i in ACB*; do
cd ${i}
  mv scanID* ${i/scanID/${PWD##*/}};
cd ..
done
```

Comment: You need to add a second loop which loops over the files in the dir and then `mv` each file, one by one. `mv` with more than two args expects last arg to be a directory and moves all files into that directory. You cannot use `mv scanID*`

Comment: You also use scanID in your script, yet list filenames as scanAC in question text.

Comment: Yes these names are different on different servers, fortunately only requires me to change those two letters in the script to get it working on both. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0):

For "couple of files" script have to be modified a little

```
for d in ACB* ; do
    for f in ${d}/scanID* ; do
        mv "${f}" "${f/scanID/${d}}"
       #mv "${f}" "${d}/${d}${f#*scanID}"
    done
done
```

Or use **find** instead

```
find ACB* -name 'scanID*' -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" ""${0/scanID/${0%\/*}}"' {} \;
```

Comment: This does not work, output using echo is:  mv ACB_200315/ACB_200315/scanID_typefile_2S.dcm ACB_200315/ACB_200315ACB200315/scanID_typefile_2S.dcm

Comment: @SSK try new version

Answer (score 0):

Got it working using the following script, adapted the one provided by Costas which did not work at first:

```
for d in ACB*; do
  cd ${d}
    for f in scanID*; do
    mv "${f}" "${d}${f#scanID}" 
    done
  cd ..
done
```